# How to cancel local push notification when user is on screen chat?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, push-notification

Someone know how can I cancel local push notifications when user is on a particular screen? 
I'm using react-native-push-notification that should stop getting notifications when the user is in the chat screen and resume this action when he lives...

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotifications();` in the component's `ComponentDidMount` method.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are trying to implement push notification sending only when the user's app is in background mode. 
Why don't you just use offline push notifications for this case?

Many backend providers like [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/) have this option. So, you just need to manage [app states](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate) to handle background mode via `AppState.currentState` and make sure that the device is subscribed to pushes.

Or do you mean you need to send pushes when the user is in the app, but on another chat screen too?